# Capturing Layer Undo button or Ctrl+Z in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, layers, features, undo-redo

I added some features in a layer. If I try to undo features from QGIS menu or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> can I capture that trigger?

I need like this:

```py
def fun():
  print('UNDO')

iface.undo.triggered.connect(fun)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must first access undo action (`mActionUndo`), then you can use its `triggered` event.

```
undo_action = [a for a in iface.digitizeToolBar().actions() if a.objectName() == "mActionUndo"][0]

def fun():
    print('UNDO')

undo_action.triggered.connect(fun)
```